# Question regarding inheritance

Tags: quran, tafseer, inheritance

1. I just finished reading surah An-Nisaa' and I was wondering how the rules of inheritance found in ayat 11, 12 and 176 are applied regarding no parents, no siblings but 3 sons and 3 daughters and the wife of the man. How is the inheritance divided then? Or no parents, no siblings and no wife but 2 sons and 2 daughters or any other specific case.
2. Is there a rule where the first born son will get more than the second born son and without loss of generality does this apply also for the second born over the third born?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this website as an inheritance calculator: http://inheritance.ilmsummit.org/projects/inheritance/home.aspx

But, to clarify how your specific cases work, anyone specifically given an inheritance in those verses is given their amount, then what is left is given to the children with the sons getting double the amount of the daughters.

The inheritance of the wife is 1/8 if they have children as the verse says.

What is left is 7/8 and that is divided between the three sons and three daughters with the sons being double the amount of the daughters.

So, 2d = s and 3s + 3d = 7/8

That is a simple enough system of equations to solve. It comes out to 7/72 for each daughter and 14/72 for each son.

When there is no wife and two sons and two daughters, the whole amount is divided between the two sons and daughters. Each son would get a third and each daughter would get a sixth. So, each son gets double the inheritance of the daughter as Allah says.

The sons all get equal amounts and there is no special increase for how old they are.